# Countably infinite

Tags: real-analysis

(a)Prove that if $E$ is countable infinite and $F \subseteq E$ is finite, then $E \cap F^c$ is countably infinite.

(a) I said that since $F \subseteq E$ then $F^c \subseteq E$ is infinite and also must be countable, since every subset of a countable set must be countable. Then therefor the intersection between two countable and infinite sets, must obviously be countably infinite. Is this on the right track? Any help would be appriciated! thanks

Comment: Every subset of a countable set is countable, but not every subset is infinite. Finite subsets are also countable. In your own example $F$ is a subset of $E$ which is not infinite.

Answer (score 1):

It sounds like you're on the right track, but with some confusions.

- I think you mean that $F^c\cap E$ is infinite, not: "$F^c\subseteq E$ is infinite." Probably, $F^c\not\subseteq E$!
- But how do you know that $F^c\cap E$ is infinite? This has nothing to do with the claim $F\subseteq E$. (In fact, we don't need the assumption "$F\subseteq E$" at all!)
- It is true that any subset of a countable set is countable. But I don't know the class you're taking - maybe you need to prove this? It's not hard, but it does take an argument (depending on what your definition of "countable" is, this argument might be one word or one or two lines).
- Your final claim, that "the intersection between two countable and infinite sets, must obviously be countably infinite" is completely wrong unfortunately: consider $\{$even integers$\}$ and $\{$odd integers$\}$. This isn't really important here - once you've concluded (point 2) that $F^c\cap E$ is infinite, and (point 3) that $F^c\cap E$ is countable, then you're done - but this does point to a possible confusion about how cardinality and sets work.

Hope this helps!

Comment: Any suggestions on how to prove that F^c∩E in infinite?

Comment: Well, think about it informally for a second: how do you *know* it's infinite? Suppose $F$ had 5 elements, and $F^c\cap E$ had 12 elements; why would this be bad?

Answer (score 0):

If a set $S$ is countably infinite it means you can find a map $f:\mathbb{N}\to S$ which is one-to-one and onto. Now in your example $E$ is countably infinite, so you already have a map like that, say $f:\mathbb{N}\to E$. But now , then $E\cap F^c = E-F$. So basically if $F$ is finite $E\cap F^c$ is the same set with finitely many points (elements) removed from it. How do you think we should manipulate $f:\mathbb{N}\to E$, to find a map $g:\mathbb{N}\to E-F$ (which is one-to-one and onto again)?